# how can I expire a session message in PHP after couple of seconds not by refreshing the page?

Tags: php, session

I need to keep this 'session' 'message' alive for couple seconds and then destroy it, Not by refreshing the page any help please!
Here is the code bellow:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
<div class="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?>">
<?php 
   echo $_SESSION['message'];
   unset($_SESSION['message']);
?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way (or any way) to do this with PHP.

Using JavaScript makes this very easy though :

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['msg_type'] ?>">
        <?php
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
        ?>
    </div>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.querySelectorAll('.alert').style.display = 'none';
        }, 5000); // Will execute this function after 5 seconds
    </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Very simple and effective, just what I was looking for thanks!